# Ruby on Rails: How and where to store meta data about database tables and fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, metadata

I have been writing rails apps for many years now, and I've had a persistent problem around database meta-information that I'm hoping there is a community solution for.

**The Problem**

As an example, 2 years ago I came onto a team with a large rails app and few developers. 2 years in I still haven't touched a large part of the apps models, or data structures. There is legacy data and structures in the database with names that are often obscure and sometimes can't even be guessed at. Today alone I came across a database field called `mth` and a table called `acbkacct`. Recently the most senior dev, (the only one who has all of the systems in his head) who has been at the company for decades is starting the process of "stepping back".

There is a story behind every table, some 30 years old, there is a story and purpose to every column. Sometimes that column is no longer used, or it's purpose shifted but its name didn't. Sometimes there are considerations and complexities that only the original developer kept mentally. I need to learn and document as much as I can about this information, but there is no obvious place to "put it" that is actually integrated with our system.

This is not the first time I've encountered such a problem, but I don't know of a community-maintained tool to solve it.

**The first solution that comes to mind**

I'm very tempted to make a new data structure `DatabaseMeta` that would allow us to store and maintain description, notes, and history information for the structures in our database. This will serve as documentation and will allow us to preserve important information about complex structures.

Obviously the structures in the database come and go and get renamed, etc. It would be trivial to have a UI indicator for tables or fields that no longer exist (and may have been deleted or renamed).

This is not actually that hard to create, but for obvious reasons I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

So I ask the community out there: how do you manage this information and what tools are available to help that are already extant?

**A second idea**

It occurs to me that perhaps some databases may have structures for this type of information natively. The database we are using is Mysql (5) and after some research I see that there is a "COMMENT" property for fields. I've never seen this used anywhere and not sure if it really fits the need. Perhaps there are databases out there that would support this type of metadata that we could store in our `schema.rb`?

Thanks!